# How to remove the row from a Visual force page using Apex Scheduler class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex, inline-visualforce, scheduled

I am Saving dates in 2 fields like follow, Using Visual force page and controller to enter multiple Row's, now i want to delete a row if the End Date is Passed Today, Can any one help me how to achieve this?

> (Long Text)Start_Date__c = 02/10/2014;03/10/2014;04/10/2014,
>
> (Long  Text)End_Date__c = 10/10/2014;11/10/2014;12/10/2014,

if the End Date is in position 2, when i delete the End date from this field the Corresponding start date should be deleted and the remaining dates should be there,
Since I am new to SF and Scheduler class I couldn't resolve this, Hope will get a help here.,

Can you Check my code and suggest me,

=====controller==========

```
public class InlineTechnicianController{
    public boolean isEdit {get;set;}
    public boolean flag {get;set;}
    public boolean isSaved {get;set;}
    public InlineTechnicianController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
            flag=false;
            isEdit=false;
            isSaved = true;
    } 
    public class TechnicianWrapper{
            public String StartDate{get;set;}
            public String EndDate{get;set;}
            public String Technician{get; set;}
    }      
          Engineer__c newList = [select Id,Start_Date_Long__c,End_Date_Long__c from Engineer__c where Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
          public List<TechnicianWrapper> techList = new List<TechnicianWrapper>();
          public List<TechnicianWrapper> getTechnician(){    
            if(techList.isEmpty()){          
              if(newList.Start_Date_Long__c!=null && newList!=null){
                    List<String> sdate,edate; 
                    sdate= newList.Start_Date_Long__c.split(';',-1);                 
                    if(newList.End_Date_Long__c!=null)
                        edate = newList.End_Date_Long__c.split(';',-1);                                                                   
                    for(Integer iterator=0;iterator<sdate.size();iterator++){
                        TechnicianWrapper instance = new TechnicianWrapper();                                      
                        if(sdate!=null)
                        instance.StartDate = sdate[iterator];
                        if(edate!=null)
                        instance.EndDate = edate[iterator];                                        
                       techList.add(instance);    
                    }}} return techList;
      }

    public PageReference editTechDate(){
            isEdit=true;
            isSaved = false;
            return null;
    }
    public PageReference addTechDate(){        
           TechnicianWrapper instance = new TechnicianWrapper();
           techList.add(instance);
           return null;    
    }

     public PageReference saveTechDate(){    
        Boolean isError=false;
        Boolean isError3=false;
        Boolean isError4=false;
        Boolean isError5=false;

        String sdt='', edt='';             
     for(TechnicianWrapper iterator:techList){      
            if(sdt==''){
                sdt = iterator.StartDate;
                edt = iterator.EndDate;                
            }else{
                sdt = sdt+';'+iterator.StartDate;
                edt = edt+';'+iterator.EndDate;                
            }
            if(iterator.startDate==''){
                isError3 = true;
            }             
            if(iterator.StartDate!='' && iterator.EndDate==''){
                isError4 = true;
            }
             if(iterator.StartDate=='' && iterator.EndDate!=''){
                isError5 = true;
            }           
        }
         Engineer__c newList= [select Id,Start_Date_Long__c,End_Date_Long__c from Engineer__c where Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
         newList.Start_Date_Long__c = sdt; 
         newList.End_Date_Long__c = edt;
         if(isError)        {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Pass and Fail cannot be selected at the same time.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }else if(isError3){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Cannot save without Start & End Dates. ');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }else if(isError4){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Cannot save without End Date');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }else if(isError5){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg=new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Cannot save without Start Date');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }else{         
                update newList;
        }  
        isEdit=false;
        isSaved = true;
    }return null;
    } }
```

====Page======

```
<apex:page controller="InlineTechnicianController" id="mypage" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form id="form1" > 
    <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlok" rendered="{!isSaved}">
  <apex:pageblockButtons location="top">
  <apex:commandButton value="Edit Dates" action="{!editTechDate}" reRender="form1"/>
      </apex:pageblockButtons> 
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Technician}" var="tc">
                    <apex:column headerValue="StartDate"><apex:outputText value="{!tc.StartDate}" ></apex:outputText></apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="EndDate"><apex:outputText value="{!tc.EndDate}"></apex:outputText></apex:column>                                       
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>        
      </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlok1" rendered="{!isEdit}">
  <apex:pageblockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addTechDate}" reRender="form1"/> 
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Row" action="{!saveTechDate}" reRender="form1"/>
     </apex:pageblockButtons>     
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Technician}" var="tc">
                    <apex:column headerValue="StartDate"><apex:inputText value="{!tc.StartDate}" size="10" id="demo" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false);"></apex:inputText></apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="EndDate"><apex:inputText value="{!tc.EndDate}" size="10" id="demo1" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false);"></apex:inputText></apex:column>                    
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>        
      </apex:pageBlock>       
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think the solution here would be to save the start and end date pairs in a separate object en link them to the original object. In that way you can simply remove records from that table on a schedule.

Comment: Hi Karti, I am kinda confused with your requirement. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: Can u check my code and suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the date values at the back end and displaying it on your VF page, you can run a schedule batch and update the object records. If you can explain this a little more, I can help you out in more detailed manner.

Thanks
Akash

Comment: Hi Akash, Can you check my code and suggest me. I have added my code here Thanks.